# how to break data of an array into rows in php saved in json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array like:

```
array{"obj_target1":"Test1","obj_count1":"3","remarks1":"Done",
"obj_target2":"Test2","obj_count2":"3","remarks2":"Running",
"obj_target3":"Test3","obj_count3":"3","remarks3":"Pending"}
```

I want to display it in 3 rows in `php`?

Comment: Post your expected output

Comment: After decoding it how to print it in 3 respective rows

Comment: I think OP want three coloumns with object_header , ob_count and remarks. And that the the data be aligned like that...

Comment: My expected out put is:       Obj_Target       Obj_Count    Remarks
                 Test1              3           Done
                 Test2              3           Running
                 Test3              3           Pending

Comment: however answer should be like i can add more data and display accordingly in respective rows

Answer (score 0):

I hope I didn't misunderstand your question

```
<?php
$json = '{"obj_target1":"Test1","obj_count1":"3","remarks1":"Done", "obj_target2":"Test2","obj_count2":"3","remarks2":"Running", "obj_target3":"Test3","obj_count3":"3","remarks3":"Pending"}';
$array = json_decode($json,true);
$output = array();
for($i=1;$i<count($array)/3+1;$i++) {
    $tmp = array();
    $tmp['obj_target'] = (isset($array['obj_target'.$i]) ? $array['obj_target'.$i] : '');
    $tmp['obj_count'] = (isset($array['obj_count'.$i]) ? $array['obj_count'.$i] : '');
    $tmp['remarks'] = (isset($array['remarks'.$i]) ? $array['remarks'.$i] : '');
    $output[] = $tmp;
}

// print_r($output);
// // OR
// echo json_encode($output);

?>
    Obj_Target Obj_Count Remarks <? foreach($output as $x){ echo $x['obj_target'] . ' ' . $x['obj_count'] . ' ' . $x['remarks'];} ?>
<hr />
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>obj_target</th>
        <th>obj_count</th>
        <th>remarks</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <? foreach($output as $x): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><? echo $x['obj_target']; ?></td>
            <td><? echo $x['obj_count']; ?></td>
            <td><? echo $x['remarks']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <? endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @FarooqSheikh like what !

Comment: Obj_Target       Obj_Count    Remarks
Test1              3           Done
Test2              3           Running
Test3              3           Pending

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$input = '{"obj_target1":"Test1","obj_count1":"3","remarks1":"Done", "obj_target2":"Test2","obj_count2":"3","remarks2":"Running", "obj_target3":"Test3","obj_count3":"3","remarks3":"Pending"}';
$arr = json_decode($input, true);
$result = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
 $index = substr($key, -1, 1);
 $result[$index][substr($key, 0, strlen($key) -1)] = $val;
}
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you want something like this.
to display in table

```
$json = '{"obj_target1":"Test1","obj_count1":"3","remarks1":"Done", "obj_target2":"Test2","obj_count2":"3","remarks2":"Running", "obj_target3":"Test3","obj_count3":"3","remarks3":"Pending"}';
$array = json_decode($json,true);
$output = array_chunk($array, 3, true);
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Obj_Target</td><td>Obj_Count</td><td>Remarks</td></tr>";
foreach ($output AS $dataArr) {
    $dataval = array_values($dataArr);
    echo "<tr><td>{$dataval[0]}</td><td>{$dataval[1]}</td><td>{$dataval[2]}</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

to display as string

```
$json = '{"obj_target1":"Test1","obj_count1":"3","remarks1":"Done", "obj_target2":"Test2","obj_count2":"3","remarks2":"Running", "obj_target3":"Test3","obj_count3":"3","remarks3":"Pending"}';
$array = json_decode($json,true);
$output = array_chunk($array, 3, true);
echo "Obj_Target, Obj_Count, Remarks<br/>";
foreach ($output AS $dataArr) {
    echo implode(', ', $dataArr)."<br/>";
}
```

But i think if the json structure is like as below, it will be more good

[
  {
    "obj_target": "Test1",
    "obj_count": "3",
    "remarks": "Done"
  },
  {
    "obj_target": "Test2",
    "obj_count": "3",
    "remarks": "Running"
  },
  {
    "obj_target": "Test3",
    "obj_count": "3",
    "remarks": "Pending"
  }
]

Then the display will be:-

```
$json = '[ { "obj_target": "Test1", "obj_count": "3", "remarks": "Done" }, { "obj_target": "Test2", "obj_count": "3", "remarks": "Running" }, { "obj_target": "Test3", "obj_count": "3", "remarks": "Pending" } ]';
$array = json_decode($json,true);
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Obj_Target</td><td>Obj_Count</td><td>Remarks</td></tr>";
foreach ($array AS $dataArr) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$dataArr['obj_target']}</td><td>{$dataArr['obj_count']}</td><td>{$dataArr['remarks']}</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks to all for reply and efforts may u live long and have happy life to all  especially @santhy.... thanks it worked for me.